# How to create a function which can be used throughout your application

Tags: objective-c, function, global

I need to access a function all over the place within my Xcode iPhone application but can not figure out how to do it.   Can anyone help me?

Here is some background:
I have a multi view application.
From anyone of the views and even within some classes I need to call a function.  The function isn't big but I keep duplicating it all over the place in order to use it. 
I would like to have only one instance of the function and just call it whenever I need it.

The function returns a random number between a start and end value.

```
-(int)PickRandomNumberFrom:(int)startnum To:(int)endnum;
```

I am sure at some point I will have other functions I need access the same way.

Comment: That's not a function, it's a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a class that handles all of your static methods.  Then you can simply include that class anytime you want access to those methods.

Objective C doesn't have static methods really, but it does have class methods which function similarly.

Class methods are declared using a '+' instead of a '-' in your .h.

```
+ (int)PickRandomNumberFrom:(int)startnum To:(int)endnum;
```

Comment: Does this mean I can only created classes to hold the global functions (or static methods)?   This means I will need to pass around a class pointer everywhere I need to call my functions.

Comment: You don't need a class pointer to call a static method.  You can simply just call the method as long as you include the .h: [[classname class] staticMethod];

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Declare it in separate .h file, for example, `PickRandomNumber.h` and implement it in `PickRandomNumber.c` file.

In all places where you need to call it, just write before `@implementation`

```
#import "PickRandomNumber.h"
```

And I suggest to declare it like C-function:

```
int pickRandomNumber(int startnum, int endnum);
```

Then you call it, for example, like this:

```
int randomNumber = pickRandomNumber(10, 15);
```

Comment: I would name the implementation file `.c` instead of `.m` just to point out that there is no class in that file.

Comment: The compiler won't recognize Objective-c syntax in a file with a `.c` extension, so you'd almost always be better off sticking with the `.m` extension. It usually only makes sense to use `.c` if the file needs to be shared with some other, non-Objective-C codebase.

Comment: Believe it or not I had tried that before posting my question.  When I created the .H and .C files I got a compiler warning "implicit declaration of function ... " on the arc4random() function.